# Crash free user statistic variation

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I was checking the crashlytics on firebase. I was seeing crash free users as 92.66% but it is not matching the actual crashes and the users.

The number of users who experienced crashes are 148
The number of active users in the same time periods are 8500

So the number of crash free user should be 8500-148 = 8352 crash free users
And the crash free percentages should be (8352/8500)*100 = 98.26% crash free users

As we can see, there is huge variation of 5.4%. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Also asked on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/L-gb3vS0mUQ/m/MTvtxNL7CwAJ

Answer (score 0):

The crash free user stats is not an average but an aggregate. Check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=ios&authuser=0&hl=en#cfu-calculation), it explains how this is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of the chart would help, it usually doesn't have big variations.

However something that I've noticed is that the total users is based on the downloads and not on the number of users that had a session during the period. (active users)